# ToastUI Calendar Dependency requirement

Tags: javascript, calendar, jscalendar

I was trying to work with Toast UI calendar available here:
https://github.com/nhn/tui.calendar
I tried to use it via CDN which requires us to insert the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui-calendar/latest/tui-calendar.css" />

<!-- If you use the default popups, use this. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui.date-picker/latest/tui-date-picker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui.time-picker/latest/tui-time-picker.css" />

<script src="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui.code-snippet/latest/tui-code-snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui.dom/v3.0.0/tui-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui.time-picker/latest/tui-time-picker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui.date-picker/latest/tui-date-picker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui-calendar/latest/tui-calendar.js"></script>
```

When I tried to create a calendar in my html file, I noticed that it lacked a few functions such as date-picker, render-range, or even the event scheduler pop-up. I also noticed that they talk of tui-code-snippet as a dependency for this calendar:
https://github.com/nhn/tui.calendar#-dependency
However, I'm not sure what to include from the tui-code-snippet exactly, as there are a bunch of functions in there and they state that we should only import the functions we need from it:
https://github.com/nhn/tui.code-snippet#-usage

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: I added the following tui-code-snippet file as well, and this only helped me to get the calendar to show/render, but all the functionalities are still missing:

```
<script src="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui.code-snippet/latest/tui-code-snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code lacks a few js links such as :

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chance/1.0.13/chance.min.js"></script>
```

Once these links are attached, we simply need to create a `tui.calendar` instance and then post the custom options as required. An example of such can be:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var cal, resizeThrottled;
    var useCreationPopup = true;
    var useDetailPopup = true;
    var datePicker, selectedCalendar;

    cal = new tui.Calendar('#calendar', {
    defaultView: 'week',
    useCreationPopup: useCreationPopup,
    useDetailPopup: useDetailPopup,
    calendars: CalendarList,
    template: {
        milestone: function(model) {
            return '<span class="calendar-font-icon ic-milestone-b"></span> <span style="background-color: ' + model.bgColor + '">' + model.title + '</span>';
        },
        allday: function(schedule) {
            return getTimeTemplate(schedule, true);
        },
        time: function(schedule) {
            return getTimeTemplate(schedule, false);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

and it should load the calendar just fine, and allow adding events to the scheduler.
I hope this helps anyone else stuck in a similar problem.

Comment: I believe that  chance.min.js is only needed in the examples provided as a random generator for their Json schedules. You don´t really need it to get the calendar working.

Comment: Yes, the idea was to get the calendar to the same place as the demo and move ahead from there. Obviously, this helps when figuring out exactly what you see in the demo and if you wish to replicate that.